# How to get the value of textbox where checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to ask how to get the value of the textbox using the checkedbox as id
this is my code

```
 <html>
 <tr>            
 <td><input type='checkbox' name='check[]'     value=".$rows["caid"].">".$rows["caid"]."</td>

 <td>".$rows["cadate"]."</td> 
 <td>".$rows["name"]."</td>
 <td>".$rows["department"]."</td>
 <td>".$rows["position"]."</td>
 <td>".$rows["ramount"]."</td>
 <td>".$rows["reason"]."</td>
 <td><input type='text' name='amt[]' VALUE=".$rows["ramount"]."></td>           
 </tr>'
```

Comment: using jQuery or PHP?

Comment: I'm sure you can find the answer by searching a little...

Comment: @Satpal I think the OPs source code is part of a `PHP` loop. - fetching from the database and constructing/building the table so I can only assume this would then be `echo`'ed into the HTML. It doesn't help that the OP has spammed the tag. **css** has no involvement or any use of it within this post.

Comment: @NewToJS I think Satpal meant does the OP want to read the text value in PHP or JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <tr>            
 <td><input type='checkbox' name='check[]'     value=".$rows["caid"].">".$rows["caid"]."</td>

 <td>".$rows["cadate"]."</td> 
 <td>".$rows["name"]."</td>
 <td>".$rows["department"]."</td>
 <td>".$rows["position"]."</td>
 <td>".$rows["ramount"]."</td>
 <td>".$rows["reason"]."</td>
 <td><input type='text' name='amt[$rows["caid"]' VALUE=".$rows["ramount"]."></td>           
 </tr>'
```

You can get the value by using the index you get from the checkbox.

```
$amounts =  $_POST['amt'];
foreach($_POST['check'] as $key => $val) {
   echo  $amounts[$val]; //this is what you need
}
```

Comment: thnks help really appreciated

Comment: The problem is if i have a multiple row it display the last value in the textbox

Comment: Do you want specific textbox value based on id, is that what you want?

Comment: yes, i want to choose an specific id and get the textbox in the same row thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer above to change your input name to <td><input type='text' name='amt[$rows["caid"]' VALUE=".$rows["ramount"]."></td>

Comment: name='amt[$rows["caid"]'  I want to ask about the name it looks like its missing " ] "

Comment: i still get this parse error syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: Can you post your code to identify what's causing the error.

Comment: i already check the code and find the error thnx a lot sir @Jeffrey Hitosis

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input [name^=check]").find(":checked").val()
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. OP wants to get the value of the text input in the same row as the checkbox, not the checkbox itself

Comment: Yes i want to get the value of textbox in the same row of the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery:

> $("input[type='checkbox']").val();

Using PHP

> $check = $_GET['check'];

Get this Value Of

```
<input type='text' name='amt[]' VALUE=".$rows["ramount"].">
```

> $amt= $_GET['amt'];

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. OP wants to get the value of the text input in the same row as the checkbox, not the checkbox itself